# Animation using multiple ellipses and controlled using keyPressed

Tags: processing

The code I have here is an animation that shows one circle that moves the way I'd like it to. I'd like to have 10 circles and I assume I use a loop or possibly an array but I'm not quite sure how to do that. At the same time, I want to make it so that at first the animation doesn't move but starts moving when I press a specific key and stops when I press the same key.

```java
color a = color(random(255), random(255), random(255), random(125, 250));
float dia = random(60, 80);
float x;
float y;

float speedX = random(-3, 3);
float speedY = random(-3, 3);

void setup() { 
  background(255);


size(400, 200);
  x = random(dia/2, width-dia/2);
  y = random(dia/2, height-dia/2);

}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  noStroke();
  fill(a);
  ellipse(x, y, dia, dia);
  x = x + speedX;
  y = y + speedY;
  if(speedX > 0 && x >= width - dia/2) {
    speedX = speedX * -1;
  }
  if(speedX < 0 && x <= dia/2) {
    speedX = speedX * -1;
  }
  if(speedY > 0 && y >= height - dia/2) {
    speedY = speedY * -1;
  } 
  if(speedY < 0 && y <= dia/2) {
    speedY = speedY * -1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get multiple circles by **encapsulating** the data you need to draw a circle into a **class**. It might look something like this:

```java
Circle c;

void setup() { 
  size(400, 200);
  c = new Circle();
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  c.draw();
}

class Circle {
  color a = color(random(255), random(255), random(255), random(125, 250));
  float dia = random(60, 80);
  float x = random(dia/2, width-dia/2);
  float y = random(dia/2, height-dia/2);

  float speedX = random(-3, 3);
  float speedY = random(-3, 3);

  void draw() {
    noStroke();
    fill(a);
    ellipse(x, y, dia, dia);
    x = x + speedX;
    y = y + speedY;
    if (speedX > 0 && x >= width - dia/2) {
      speedX = speedX * -1;
    }
    if (speedX < 0 && x <= dia/2) {
      speedX = speedX * -1;
    }
    if (speedY > 0 && y >= height - dia/2) {
      speedY = speedY * -1;
    } 
    if (speedY < 0 && y <= dia/2) {
      speedY = speedY * -1;
    }
  }
}
```

Then to get multiple circles, you'd just create multiple instances of your `Circle` class and add them to an `ArrayList`:

```java
ArrayList<Circle> circles = new ArrayList<Circle>();

void setup() { 
  size(400, 200);
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    circles.add(new Circle());
  }
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  for (Circle c : circles) {
    c.draw();
  }
}
```

For the user interaction, have a look at the event methods like `mousePressed()` or `keyPressed()`. [The Processing reference](https://processing.org/reference/) should be your first stop. Good luck.

Comment: I took your advice which worked but tried making the circles appear as an image and then have them start moving when I press the space bar but when I press it, it's just a static image and only moves when I hold down the space bar. Not sure what I'm doing wrong

Tried putting the code for the ellipse in setup so it would come out as the first thing you see but there was only one circle and after I pressed the spacebar only that circle moved

With keyPressed, I assume there needs to be an else statement which says to stop and display the animation where it is but I don't know how to do that